# C++ Access Violation When using external dll function

Tags: c#, c++

Im trying to convert my code from c# to c++. The C# code calls a native function in win32u.dll. It works in c#, but when i run the c++ function, i get this error: https://gyazo.com/694d768a7392ed67f849f4db4988d7e9

C# Code:

```
[DllImport("win32u.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern IntPtr NtTokenManagerCreateFlipObjectReturnTokenHandle(int code, void* param1, void* param2, void* param3);

    public static void StackOverflowExample()
    {
        NtTokenManagerCreateFlipObjectReturnTokenHandle(0, null, null, null);
    }
```

C++ Code:

void test() {

```
HMODULE hModule = LoadLibrary(L"win32u.dll");

void* procAddr = (void*)GetProcAddress(hModule, "NtTokenManagerCreateFlipObjectReturnTokenHandle");

using tFunction = intptr_t(__stdcall*)(int, void*, void*, void*);
const auto control = static_cast<tFunction>((void*)procAddr);

control(0, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

}

Comment: The c# code is calling unmanaged code. Im not trying to call the c# function from c++.

Comment: My code works in C#, im just having issues getting it to work in c++.

Comment: OK, Whence does the declaration of `NtTokenManagerCreateFlipObjectReturnTokenHandle` come when building/compiling your C++ code? I can't find any reference online. Would be nice to see its ***precise*** signature.

Comment: It is part of window's build in win32u.dll so i have no idea. My code works perfectly in C# so i would assume its something close to it.

Comment: Try using this: `tFunction control = reinterpret_cast<tFunction>(procAddr);` just in case there's a problem in static- and/or const- casting

Comment: Unfortuneatly that didnt work either. Still getting an access violation.

Comment: @NickBrown Check if the dll actually lies in the same directory, otherwise specify the exact path to it.